# DateAdd SQL Code Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, dateadd

i keep getting the below error when running this SQL code in an access query. Any idea why?

Error:
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ' Status Date'

Code:

```
FROM [Owner Training Report]
WHERE ((([Owner Training Report].[Status Date])>DateAdd("m",12,Date())) AND (([Owner Training Report].[Reporting Basic Status])="Completed"));
```

Comment: Please show **full** SQL as error can be due to another part of query.

Answer (score 1):

You may have *Null* values, so try:

```
WHERE (Nz([Status Date],Date()) > DateAdd("m",12,Date())) AND ([Reporting Basic Status] = "Completed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I cannot be 100% sure as I don't know what is your full query):

```
FROM [Owner Training Report]
WHERE ((([Owner Training Report].[Status Date])>DateAdd('m',12,Date())) AND (([Owner Training Report].[Reporting Basic Status])='Completed'));
```

I basically changed " to '